# What is the java source code or method for 'Player name must be between 3 and 25 characters long'?

Tags: java

As I have shown the codes below, option 1 initiates setting up a player name but it has to be between 3 and 25 characters long and also should not have any blank space. What logic and methods should be used behind this reason after the (String name = " ") statement?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Game
{
    private Player player;


    public Game()
    {
      this.player = null;
    }

    public void showMenu()
    {
        while(true)
        {
           System.out.println("=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=");
           System.out.println("Welcome to Lucky Vending Machine Game");
           System.out.println("=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=");
           System.out.println("Please select 1 to Register a Player");
           System.out.println("Please select 2 to Play a Round");
           System.out.println("Please select 3 to View Round Information");
           System.out.println("Please select 4 to Get Help");
           System.out.println("Please select 5 to Exit");
           System.out.println("Choose an option: ");

           Scanner menuScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
           int option = menuScanner.nextInt();

           if (option < 1 || option > 5)
           {
            System.out.println("Error: Please, choose a number from 1 to 5");
            continue;
           }
           else if(option == 1)
           {
               System.out.println("Please enter the player name");
               Scanner playerName = new Scanner(System.in);
               String name = " ";
               player = new Player(name);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you initliazing `String name = " ";` ? and why is `playerName` not used

Comment: This isn't the kind of question that Stack Overflow does well at. This is just the nuts and bolts of programming. You'd do better to find a friend who can help you get up to speed to a basic level of competence. This problem that you're working on is a reasonable starting point, but you may actually be better off working through https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 3):

```
public boolean isValidName(String playerName) {
    int length = playerName.length();
    return ((length >= 3 && length <= 25) && !playerName.contains(" "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below piece of code, here I am including only else part

```
   else if(option == 1)
   {
       System.out.println("Please enter the player name");
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       String name = " ";
       name = scanner.next(); // return type for next() is string
       if(name.length()>=3 && name.length()<=25 && !name.contains(" ")){
          player = new Player(name);
       }else{
          System.out.println('Name length should be between 3 and 25 characters");
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, no need for **another** Scanner. The first scanner can be used for the `playerName` scanning.

Second, it's somehow a basic grammar.

```
else if(option == 1)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter the player name");
    String name = menuScanner.next();
    if (name.length >= 3 && name.length <= 25 && !Pattern.compile("\\s").matcher(name).find())
    {
        // valid name
        player = new Player(name);
    }
    else
    {
        // invalid name, do some warning output and ask user to reenter again.
    }
}
```

Note that "blank space" may not only contains white space, but maybe a `\t` too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this,

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String PlayerName = "";
do {
    System.out.println("Enter a player's name");
    PlayerName = sc.nextLine(); 
    if((PlayerName.length()<3 && PlayerName.length()>25)|| PlayerName.contains(" "))
        System.out.println("Invalid number !!!");
    }while((PlayerName.length()<3 && PlayerName.length()>25) || PlayerName.contains(" "));
```

If you have more validations, you can use the **.matches()** method by passing the regular expression in it.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I am very new to java to be frank and my question seemed to have a little research effort. From now on I will try to put more research along I go ahead with my Java foundations before I put any questions. However, Thank you everyone for helping me out in this.